# SQL GROUP BY and NULL values: How can I group my results by only non-null values?

Tags: sql, mysql

My query:

```
SELECT *,
    contacts.createdAt AS contactcreatedAt,
    contacts.updatedAt AS contactupdatedAt,
    bidresponses.itemid AS bidresponseitemid,
    bidresponses.personid AS bidresponsepersonid,
    SUM(tagsitems.quantity) AS totalquantity
FROM items
LEFT OUTER JOIN tagsitems ON items.id = tagsitems.itemid
LEFT OUTER JOIN itemscontacts ON items.id = itemscontacts.itemid
LEFT OUTER JOIN contacts ON itemscontacts.contactid = contacts.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN bidresponses ON items.id = bidresponses.itemid AND itemscontacts.personid = bidresponses.personid
LEFT OUTER JOIN bidtemplatefields ON bidresponses.bidtemplatefieldid = bidtemplatefields.id
WHERE ( (items.id = 70687 OR items.id = 70595) AND itemscontacts.relationship = 's' ) AND ( items.deletedAt IS NULL )
GROUP BY items.id, tagsitems.itemid, bidresponses.personid, bidresponses.bidtemplatefieldid
ORDER BY items.id ASC
```

Without the **SUM()** and **GROUP BY** clauses this query returns the desired results, minus the important totalquantity value.

The task that has got me stumped at the moment is constructing the GROUP BY clause so that it "ignores" NULL or missing values from bidresponses. The data is such that the results will be a mixed set of items - some have entries in the bidresponses table and some do not.

**EDIT**:
I want the entries with NULL values in the bidresponses table to show up. With the current GROUP BY clause they are not. **I should note that the only reason I am using the grouping at all is so that I can get the totalquantity value**. Here is an example of the query output **without** the SUM() and GROUP BY clauses:

```
+-------+------------+------+---------------------------+------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+-------+--------+----------+--------+-----------+----------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+------+-----------+----------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------+-------------+----------+------+------------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| id    | itemtypeid | code | description               | cost | unittypeid | projectid | companyid | createdAt           | updatedAt           | deletedAt | unittype | tagid | itemid | quantity | itemid | contactid | personid | sentdate            | responsedate | bidtemplateid | relationship | awarddate | assigndate | id   | companyid | personid | companyidOwner | parentContactid | createdAt           | updatedAt           | firstName | lastName | company             | email               | bidtemplatefieldid | itemid | bidresponse | personid | id   | bidtemplatefield | fieldtypeid | contactcreatedAt    | contactupdatedAt    | bidresponseitemid | bidresponsepersonid |
+-------+------------+------+---------------------------+------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+-------+--------+----------+--------+-----------+----------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+------+-----------+----------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------+-------------+----------+------+------------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 70595 |          1 | NULL | HD Banners                | NULL |       NULL |         7 |         1 | 2010-05-10 17:00:11 | 2010-08-14 18:57:41 | NULL      | each     |  NULL |   NULL |     NULL |  70595 |        16 |    34789 | 2010-08-14 22:37:01 |         NULL |             1 | s            |      NULL |       NULL |   16 |      NULL |     NULL |              1 |            NULL | 2010-08-05 18:40:01 | 2010-08-05 18:41:40 | NULL      | NULL     | sdf                 | 23523@wokd.com      |               NULL |   NULL | NULL        |     NULL | NULL | NULL             |        NULL | 2010-08-05 18:40:01 | 2010-08-05 18:41:40 |              NULL |                NULL |
| 70595 |          1 | NULL | HD Banners                | NULL |       NULL |         7 |         1 | 2010-05-10 17:00:11 | 2010-08-14 18:57:41 | NULL      | each     |  NULL |   NULL |     NULL |  70595 |        22 |    34794 | 2010-08-14 18:44:02 |         NULL |             1 | s            |      NULL |       NULL |   22 |      NULL |    34794 |              1 |            NULL | 2010-08-09 19:56:28 | 2010-08-10 13:55:03 | NULL      | NULL     | anewwwww            | hmm@hmm.com         |               NULL |   NULL | NULL        |     NULL | NULL | NULL             |        NULL | 2010-08-09 19:56:28 | 2010-08-10 13:55:03 |              NULL |                NULL |
| 70595 |          1 | NULL | HD Banners                | NULL |       NULL |         7 |         1 | 2010-05-10 17:00:11 | 2010-08-14 18:57:41 | NULL      | each     |  NULL |   NULL |     NULL |  70595 |        27 |    34797 | 2010-08-14 22:36:59 |         NULL |             1 | s            |      NULL |       NULL |   27 |      NULL |     NULL |              1 |            NULL | 2010-08-10 19:11:52 | NULL                | NULL      | NULL     | 3k3jdjhgj@wrwer.com | 3k3jdjhgj@wrwer.com |               NULL |   NULL | NULL        |     NULL | NULL | NULL             |        NULL | 2010-08-10 19:11:52 | NULL                |              NULL |                NULL |
| 70595 |          1 | NULL | HD Banners                | NULL |       NULL |         7 |         1 | 2010-05-10 17:00:11 | 2010-08-14 18:57:41 | NULL      | each     |  NULL |   NULL |     NULL |  70595 |        28 |    34798 | 2010-08-14 22:37:00 |         NULL |             1 | s            |      NULL |       NULL |   28 |      NULL |     NULL |              1 |            NULL | 2010-08-10 19:18:27 | NULL                | NULL      | NULL     | 3838474@234234.com  | 3838474@234234.com  |               NULL |   NULL | NULL        |     NULL | NULL | NULL             |        NULL | 2010-08-10 19:18:27 | NULL                |              NULL |                NULL |
| 70687 |          1 | NULL | Editing and adding labels | NULL |       NULL |         7 |         1 | 2010-05-15 07:26:33 | 2010-08-14 18:55:48 | NULL      | each     |    12 |  70687 |     NULL |  70687 |        16 |    34789 | 2010-08-14 22:37:01 |         NULL |             1 | s            |      NULL |       NULL |   16 |      NULL |     NULL |              1 |            NULL | 2010-08-05 18:40:01 | 2010-08-05 18:41:40 | NULL      | NULL     | sdf                 | 23523@wokd.com      |               NULL |   NULL | NULL        |     NULL | NULL | NULL             |        NULL | 2010-08-05 18:40:01 | 2010-08-05 18:41:40 |              NULL |                NULL |
| 70687 |          1 | NULL | Editing and adding labels | NULL |       NULL |         7 |         1 | 2010-05-15 07:26:33 | 2010-08-14 18:55:48 | NULL      | each     |     2 |  70687 |     NULL |  70687 |        16 |    34789 | 2010-08-14 22:37:01 |         NULL |             1 | s            |      NULL |       NULL |   16 |      NULL |     NULL |              1 |            NULL | 2010-08-05 18:40:01 | 2010-08-05 18:41:40 | NULL      | NULL     | sdf                 | 23523@wokd.com      |               NULL |   NULL | NULL        |     NULL | NULL | NULL             |        NULL | 2010-08-05 18:40:01 | 2010-08-05 18:41:40 |              NULL |                NULL |
| 70687 |          1 | NULL | Editing and adding labels | NULL |       NULL |         7 |         1 | 2010-05-15 07:26:33 | 2010-08-14 18:55:48 | NULL      | each     |    12 |  70687 |     NULL |  70687 |        27 |    34797 | 2010-08-14 22:36:59 |         NULL |             1 | s            |      NULL |       NULL |   27 |      NULL |     NULL |              1 |            NULL | 2010-08-10 19:11:52 | NULL                | NULL      | NULL     | 3k3jdjhgj@wrwer.com | 3k3jdjhgj@wrwer.com |               NULL |   NULL | NULL        |     NULL | NULL | NULL             |        NULL | 2010-08-10 19:11:52 | NULL                |              NULL |                NULL |
| 70687 |          1 | NULL | Editing and adding labels | NULL |       NULL |         7 |         1 | 2010-05-15 07:26:33 | 2010-08-14 18:55:48 | NULL      | each     |     2 |  70687 |     NULL |  70687 |        27 |    34797 | 2010-08-14 22:36:59 |         NULL |             1 | s            |      NULL |       NULL |   27 |      NULL |     NULL |              1 |            NULL | 2010-08-10 19:11:52 | NULL                | NULL      | NULL     | 3k3jdjhgj@wrwer.com | 3k3jdjhgj@wrwer.com |               NULL |   NULL | NULL        |     NULL | NULL | NULL             |        NULL | 2010-08-10 19:11:52 | NULL                |              NULL |                NULL |
| 70687 |          1 | NULL | Editing and adding labels | NULL |       NULL |         7 |         1 | 2010-05-15 07:26:33 | 2010-08-14 18:55:48 | NULL      | each     |    12 |  70687 |     NULL |  70687 |        28 |    34798 | 2010-08-14 22:37:00 |         NULL |             1 | s            |      NULL |       NULL |   28 |      NULL |     NULL |              1 |            NULL | 2010-08-10 19:18:27 | NULL                | NULL      | NULL     | 3838474@234234.com  | 3838474@234234.com  |               NULL |   NULL | NULL        |     NULL | NULL | NULL             |        NULL | 2010-08-10 19:18:27 | NULL                |              NULL |                NULL |
| 70687 |          1 | NULL | Editing and adding labels | NULL |       NULL |         7 |         1 | 2010-05-15 07:26:33 | 2010-08-14 18:55:48 | NULL      | each     |     2 |  70687 |     NULL |  70687 |        28 |    34798 | 2010-08-14 22:37:00 |         NULL |             1 | s            |      NULL |       NULL |   28 |      NULL |     NULL |              1 |            NULL | 2010-08-10 19:18:27 | NULL                | NULL      | NULL     | 3838474@234234.com  | 3838474@234234.com  |               NULL |   NULL | NULL        |     NULL | NULL | NULL             |        NULL | 2010-08-10 19:18:27 | NULL                |              NULL |                NULL |
+-------+------------+------+---------------------------+------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+-------+--------+----------+--------+-----------+----------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+------+-----------+----------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------+-------------+----------+------+------------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

Here is an example of the query output **with** the SUM() and GROUP BY clauses:

```
+-------+------------+------+---------------------------+------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+-------+--------+----------+--------+-----------+----------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+------+-----------+----------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------------+--------------------+--------+-------------+----------+------+------------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------+
| id    | itemtypeid | code | description               | cost | unittypeid | projectid | companyid | createdAt           | updatedAt           | deletedAt | unittype | tagid | itemid | quantity | itemid | contactid | personid | sentdate            | responsedate | bidtemplateid | relationship | awarddate | assigndate | id   | companyid | personid | companyidOwner | parentContactid | createdAt           | updatedAt           | firstName | lastName | company | email          | bidtemplatefieldid | itemid | bidresponse | personid | id   | bidtemplatefield | fieldtypeid | contactcreatedAt    | contactupdatedAt    | bidresponseitemid | bidresponsepersonid | totalquantity |
+-------+------------+------+---------------------------+------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+-------+--------+----------+--------+-----------+----------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+------+-----------+----------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------------+--------------------+--------+-------------+----------+------+------------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------+
| 70595 |          1 | NULL | HD Banners                | NULL |       NULL |         7 |         1 | 2010-05-10 17:00:11 | 2010-08-14 18:57:41 | NULL      | each     |  NULL |   NULL |     NULL |  70595 |        16 |    34789 | 2010-08-14 22:37:01 |         NULL |             1 | s            |      NULL |       NULL |   16 |      NULL |     NULL |              1 |            NULL | 2010-08-05 18:40:01 | 2010-08-05 18:41:40 | NULL      | NULL     | sdf     | 23523@wokd.com |               NULL |   NULL | NULL        |     NULL | NULL | NULL             |        NULL | 2010-08-05 18:40:01 | 2010-08-05 18:41:40 |              NULL |                NULL |          NULL |
| 70687 |          1 | NULL | Editing and adding labels | NULL |       NULL |         7 |         1 | 2010-05-15 07:26:33 | 2010-08-14 18:55:48 | NULL      | each     |    12 |  70687 |     NULL |  70687 |        16 |    34789 | 2010-08-14 22:37:01 |         NULL |             1 | s            |      NULL |       NULL |   16 |      NULL |     NULL |              1 |            NULL | 2010-08-05 18:40:01 | 2010-08-05 18:41:40 | NULL      | NULL     | sdf     | 23523@wokd.com |               NULL |   NULL | NULL        |     NULL | NULL | NULL             |        NULL | 2010-08-05 18:40:01 | 2010-08-05 18:41:40 |              NULL |                NULL |          NULL |
+-------+------------+------+---------------------------+------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+-------+--------+----------+--------+-----------+----------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+------+-----------+----------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------------+--------------------+--------+-------------+----------+------+------------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you completely. You want result rows with the value NULL in columns `bidresponseitemid` and `bidresponsepersonid` not to show up? Or they do not show up and you want them to?
Maybe include a example result set (you can get nice text ones by using the mysql command in a console/terminal) and describe what you want to have differently. "WHERE `bidresponsepersonid` IS NOT NULL" might be something your looking for.

Comment: thanks thomas. i will clarify above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include all of the significant un-aggregated columns in your GROUP BY clause. Right now, you do not group by createdAt etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you need all those rows `SUM()` and the therefore required `GROUP BY` will not be a good solution.

The best solution probably will be to just add the quantities up when processing/looping through all rows in your client code/script.

Alternatively you could query twice, once with `GROUP BY` and `SUM()` to get the quantity for each `items.id` however even doing a extra loop through all the rows in your client code will probably be faster than querying twice, might also depend on the size of the result.

Comment: you're right, i could do the processing client-side, but i just have a feeling that there must be a much easier way... if only i could apply some sort of WHERE rule to the GROUP clause...

Comment: `GROUP BY` will merge your rows in the way you tell it to. With a `GROUP BY items.id` you will always just get a row for that id. I'm not aware of a function that does what you want it to do. If you want to do it all with SQL you can always send 2 queries e.g.: `SELECT SUM(tagsitems.quantity) AS totalquantity, tagsitems.itemid FROM tagsitems GROUP BY tagitems.itemid` and your other one. Btw: don't use *, except you really are using 100%.

Comment: it turned out that simply changing the 3rd field in the group by clause to itemscontacts.personid instead of bidresponses.personid gives me exactly what i need!

Comment: Would be nice if you post the final query and a example result to it as an answer. I'm not 100% sure what you needed in the end.